# Exception on jsp page when validation is done through spring validator class

Tags: spring-mvc

i m facing problem in validation of spring i m using the validator class for validation ,validation is happening properly but for `int and date` type when   i provide different type like string in form field  then whole `exception` is paste on my jsp page i want to provide proper message format on that.One more thing i want to do i want to use regex in this validator class please provide a piece of code snippet of regex with any example so that i can implement in this validator class

this is my controller

```
    package com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.EmployeeForm;
    import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl;
    import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.impl.ProjectServiceImpl;
    import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.model.EmployeeBO;
    import com.nousinfo.tutorial.validator.EmployeeValidator;

    /**
     * 
     * @author ankurj
     * 
     */
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("employee")
    public class EmployeeController {

        private EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl;
        private ProjectServiceImpl projectServiceImpl;
        private EmployeeValidator employeeValidator;

        public void setEmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl) {
            this.employeeServiceImpl = employeeServiceImpl;
        }

        /**
         * Set the view to Employee Form
         * 
         * @param model
         *            is the entity mapped to form object
         * @return view
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @RequestMapping(value = "/searchspring", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String view(Model model) throws Exception {
            EmployeeBO employeeBO = new EmployeeBO();
            model.addAttribute("employeeBO", employeeBO);
            return "EmployeeForm";
        }

        public void setEmployeeValidator(EmployeeValidator employeeValidator) {
            this.employeeValidator = employeeValidator;
        }

        /**
         * set the view to "AboutUS"
         * 
         * @return VIEW
         */
        @RequestMapping(value = "/aboutUs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String aboutUsView() {
            return "AboutNous";
        }

        /**
         * This method is used to insert the detail of employee or simply create new
         * employee with detail
         * 
         * @param employeeForm
         *            is the model entity mapped to form object
         * @param bindingResult
         * @param model
         * @return
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @RequestMapping(value = "/createEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView createEmployee(
                @ModelAttribute("employeeBO") EmployeeBO employeeBO,
                BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
            employeeValidator.validate(employeeBO, bindingResult);
            System.out.println(bindingResult);
            System.out.println(employeeBO.getEmployeeNumber());
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                model.setViewName("EmployeeForm");
                return model;
            }
            model.addObject("employeeBO", employeeBO);

            if (employeeBO.getUpdateStatus() == 'A') {
                boolean flag = employeeServiceImpl.actionDecider(employeeBO);
                if (flag == false) {
                    model.setViewName("DBError");

                } else
                    model.setViewName("Success");
            }

            return model;
        }
}
```

this is my validator class

```
package com.nousinfo.tutorial.validator;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.model.EmployeeBO;

public class EmployeeValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        return EmployeeBO.class.isAssignableFrom(arg0);
    }

    public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {
        boolean found = false;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "firstName",
                "employeeBO.firstName");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "title",
                "employeeBO.title");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "city",
                "employeeBO.city");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "state",
                "employeeBO.state");

        EmployeeBO employeeBO = (EmployeeBO) object;

        if (pattern.matcher(employeeBO.getFirstName()).find()) {
            found = true;
        }
        if (found) {
            errors.rejectValue("firstName", "employeeregex.string");
        }

        if (pattern.matcher(employeeBO.getLastName()).find()) {
            found = true;
        }
        if (found) {
            errors.rejectValue("lastName", "employeeregex.string");
        }

        if (pattern.matcher(employeeBO.getCity()).find()) {
            found = true;
        }
        if (found) {
            errors.rejectValue("city", "employeeregex.string");
        }
        if (pattern.matcher(employeeBO.getState()).find()) {
            found = true;
        }
        if (found) {
            errors.rejectValue("state", "employeeregex.string");
        }
        if (employeeBO.getEmployeeNumber() == null) {

            errors.rejectValue("employeeNumber", "employeeBO.employeeNumber");

        }
        if (employeeBO.getPincode() == null) {
            errors.rejectValue("pincode", "employeeBO.pincode");

        }

        if (employeeBO.getTelephoneNumber() == null) {
            errors.rejectValue("telephoneNumber", "employeeBO.telephoneNumber");

        }
        if (employeeBO.getMobileNumber() == null)
            errors.rejectValue("mobileNumber", "employeeBO.mobileNumber");

    }

}
```

this is my jsp by which i m providing input

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/input-1.0"
    prefix="input"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Create Employee</title>
<script>
    function home() {
        window.location.href = "/EmployeeWebSpring/search/searchspring";

    }
</script>
</head>

<body background="../images/flower.jpg">

    <table width="1254" height="74" border="0" align="center">

        <tr>

            <td width="20" height="68" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img
                src="../images/Header.png" width="1300" height="92" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <br />
    </p>
    <hr size="1" width="1254">
    <h1 align="center">
        <font color="FFA54F">Employee Form</font>
    </h1>
    <form:form id="form" method="post"
        action="/EmployeeWebSpring/employee/createEmployee"
        commandName="employeeBO">
        <table align="center" class="table">
            <tr>
                <form:hidden path="updateStatus" value="A" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>EmployeeNumber:</td>


                <td><form:input path="employeeNumber" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="employeeNumber" /></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>First_Name:</td>

                <td><form:input path="firstName" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="firstName" /></font></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Last_Name:</td>

                <td><form:input path="lastName" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="lastName" /></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Title:</td>

                <td><form:input path="title" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="title" /></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Department_Id:</td>

                <td><form:input path="departmentId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address1:</td>

                <td><form:input path="address1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address2:</td>

                <td><form:input path="address2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>City:</td>

                <td><form:input path="city" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="city" /></font></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>State:</td>

                <td><form:input path="state" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="state" /></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>Pincode:</td>

                <td><form:input path="pincode" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="pincode" /></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Telephone_Number:</td>

                <td><form:input path="telephoneNumber" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="telephoneNumber" /></font></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Mobile_Number:</td>

                <td><form:input path="mobileNumber" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="mobileNumber" /></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date_Of_Birth:</td>

                <td><form:input path="dateOfBirth" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="dateOfBirth" /></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date_Of_Anniversary:</td>

                <td><form:input path="dateOfAnniversary" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="dateOfAnniversary" /></font></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Date_Of_Joining:</td>

                <td><form:input path="dateOfJoining" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="dateOfJoining" /></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date_Of_Leaving:</td>

                <td><form:input path="dateOfLeaving" /><font color="red"><form:errors
                            path="dateOfLeaving" /></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Reason_For_Leaving:</td>

                <td><form:input path="reasonForLeaving" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br>
        <br />
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <br>

        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="method" value="Save" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="home()" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr size="1" width="786">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code of the input involved in the jsp ?

Comment: @Rigg802 i have provided my jsp through which i m providing input please find the solution actually i m stuck on this problem from past four days

Comment: you changed the screenshot for 'Employee form' , the question is confusing; for future usage (for other people), you should put back the old screenshot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the fact you didn't initialize the converters in your controller.

the first thing you need to add is the `InitBinder` in your controller:

```
@InitBinder public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");  //Select the format you want
 dateFormat.setLenient(false); 
 binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
}
```

You will need different CustomEditor depending on what you want to do:

```
 binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true)); //Trim strings
 binder.registerCustomEditor(byte[].class, new ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor()); //to handle file upload
```

You can also add in your `EmployeeBO` the following annotations depending on the types you want to use:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
@DateTimeFormat(style = "S-")  //format: 'S' for short style, 'M' for medium, 'L' for long, and 'F' for full. A date or time may be ommitted by specifying a style character '-'.
private Date dateOfBirth;

@NumberFormat(style=Style.NUMBER)
private Long employeeNumberamount;
```

Comment: if u dont mind can u explain how internally these converter works  i mean custom editors of spring

Comment: Before showing the form and after submitting it, Spring intercept your form and convert the type of each variable from your "BO" (command object) to the type you defined them. If you want to know more about the InitBinder lifecyle, check the Spring documentation
Does the solution work?

Comment: yeah its working for date can u plz tell me how to handle exception on type conversion of string to integer which is throwing exception on jsp page for date its resolved if i provide string on integer field then it throws built in exception msg i want to show my own custom msg ,for that i have done one typeMismatch property of spring in property file do u know the other possible way so that i can throw my own custom msg. what happened right now its show two msg simultaneously one for field empty,and second for typemismatch msg used in property file ihave done editing on validator clas

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080441/spring-numberformatting-with-registercustomereditor-on-list-of-numbers